# About irreducible connection

Tags: dg.differential-geometry, group-actions, connections, principal-bundles, gauge-theory

The irreducible connection is a connection whose holonomy group is just $G$ (let us just assume the base space $X$ is just connected). Otherwise, it is called reducible if the holonomy group $H_A$ with respect to your connection is a proper subgroup of $Aut(E_x)=G$.

We then define the isotropy group $$\Gamma_A=\{u\in \mathcal G|u(A)=A\}=\{u\in \mathcal G|\nabla_{A} u=0\}$$
And we also know

> $\Gamma_A$ is isomorphic to the centralizer of $H_A$ in $G$.

So the above discussion shows that $\Gamma_A$ is isomorphic to $C(G)$ for irreducible connection case. But what I don't understand is the remark from [1], it claims that a way to detect whether the isotropy group is bigger than $C(G)$ is to study the $Lie(\Gamma_A)=\{f\in \Omega^0(g_E)|\nabla_A f=0\}$ to detect $$\nabla_{A}:\Omega^{0}(g_E)\rightarrow \Omega^{1}(g_E)$$
Here $g_E$ denotes the adjoint bundle(I follow Donaldson and Kronheimer's reference [2]). And the final result is: for the reducible case, this corresponds to having non-zero kernel.

1. What I don't understand is why we deduce that the reducible case corresponds to non-zero kernel?
2. Moreover, I don't understand the motivation of isotropy group detecting the (ir)redubile connection. There is a remark on [1]: the action $\mathcal G \times \mathcal A \rightarrow \mathcal A$ may not be free, so the quotient may have sigularity, thus we can define the isotropy group and compare it with $C(G)$ Can someone explain the reason behind it?
3. For example, in $G=SU(2)$ case, this can be reduced to $U(1)$, and the for reducible connection, one has $\Gamma_A/ \mathbb Z_2 \cong U(1)$, why we can reduce $SU(2)$ to $U(1)$? (I know here $C(G)=\mathbb Z_2$) And I don't understand the remark: The quotient now acts freely on the irreducible connection space $\mathcal A^*$

Thanks!

[1]: J.Labastida and M.Marino: Topological Quantum Field theory and Four Manifolds
[2]: S.Donaldson and Kronheimer:The Geometry of Four Manifolds